# Simple Character Validation in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginning programmer and new to C++, and am looking to learn.  This is what I have so far:

This psuedo-code version an instructor provided me:

```
if str.find("@")==string::npos OR <-- @ not found

str.find(".")==string::npos OR <-- . not found

str.find(" ")!=string::npos) <-- space found
```

And my understanding of the function's requirements:

```
 check emails for @, ., or space  function,

 if @ exists, no output
 if @ doesn't exist, output "This (email) is invalid."
 if . exists, no output
 if ' ' exists, output "This (email) is invalid."
```

Here is my sorry attempt that doesn't work:

```
void Roster::printIncorrectEmails()
{
char at = '@';
char pd = '.';
char sp = ' ';

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(RepoArray); i++) {

    string email = Student::RepoArray.getEmailAddress();

    size_t found = email.find(at, pd);
    if (found != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Email: " << email << '\n';
    }

    found = email.find(sp);
    if (found == string::npos)
    {

        cout << "Invalid Email: " << email << '\n';
    }
}
}
```

I've got plenty of other attempts too, if anyone cares to see them.

Comment: Recommendation: Turn your sample into a function that only does one thing, test whether or not a given string meets your validity rules. `bool isemailvalid(string email)`. This way you have a nice, simple function that doesn't depend on anything else. You can now test the stuffing out of it in isolation until you are absolutely certain it works. then you can call a function that gets an email address and pass the address into `isemailvalid` knowing that whatever bugs you may have, they aren't in `isemailvalid`.

Comment: What is the function definition of `find`? Hint : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: What's a `sizeof(RepoArray)`? What's a `RepoArray`? Consider making a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why is `pd` and `at` passed to first `find `? (at the same time)